# MERCADO PAGO me funciona correctamente en local pero al subirlo al servidor me manda el error HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, html, php7, mercadopago, backend

le comento mi situación, espero que me puedan ayudar

Estoy elaborando un proyecto de venta de cursos digitales, y tengo implementado mercado pago. En forma local ya lo termine, y lo acabo de subir a mi servidor, solo que no me funciona, me arroja el error 500 he estado checando pero no encuentro la falla, espero me puedan orientar con ello, les adjunto el codigo

```
$datos3= $conexion->query("select Cursos_venta.*,Cursos.Nombre as nombre_curso, Cursos.Imagen from 
   Cursos_venta inner join Cursos on Cursos_venta.Id_curso=Cursos.Id
   where Id_venta=".$_GET['id_venta'])or die($conexion->error);

    // SDK de Mercado Pago
require __DIR__ .  '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Agrega credenciales
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

// Crea un objeto de preferencia
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
$preference->back_urls = array(
    "success" => "https://misitioweb.com/Thankyou.php?id_venta=".$_GET['id_venta']."&metodo=mercado_pago",
    "failure" => "https://misitioweb.com/errorpago.php?error=failure",
    "pending" => "https://misitioweb.com/errorpago.php?error=pending"
);
$preference->auto_return = "approved";

// Crea un ítem en la preferencia
$datos=array();
while($f = mysqli_fetch_array($datos3)){
    $item = new MercadoPago\Item();
    $item->title = $f['7'];
    $item->quantity = $f['Cantidad'];
    $item->unit_price = $f['Precio'];
    $datos[]=$item;
}

$preference->items = $datos;
$preference->save();
 
?>
```

Aqui abajo tengo el html, tambien tengo implementado paypal pero no tengo error en ello, lo que me falla es lo de mercado pago, ayuda por favor.

```
<html>
<body>

    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=MXN"> // Replace YOUR_SB_CLIENT_ID with your sandbox client ID
  </script>
    
    <div class="site-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <span class="fa fa-check-circle display-3 text-success"></span>
            <h2 class="display-3 text-black">Eliga su Metodo de Pago</h2>
            <p class="lead mb-5"></p>
            <hr>
            <hr>
            <img src="images/version-horizontal-large.png" width="500">
            <br>
            <br>
            <!--<p><a href="index.php" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Regresar a nuestros cursos</a></p>-->
            <h4 class="h1">Total<?php echo $datosUsuario[2];?></h4>
           <form action="http://localhost/Cursos/Thankyou.php?id_venta=<?php echo $_GET['id_venta']?>&metodo=mercado_pago" method="POST">
             <script
               src="https://www.mercadopago.com.mx/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js"
               data-preference-id="<?php echo $preference->id; ?>">
             </script>
             <hr>
            </form>
            <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

   <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              amount: {
                value: '<?php echo $datosUsuario[2];?>',
              },
            }]
          });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            console.log(details);
            if(details.status == 'COMPLETED'){
                 location.href="./Thankyou.php?id_venta=<?php echo $_GET['id_venta'];?>&metodo=paypal";
            }
           
          });
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container'); // Display payment options on your web page
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Estos errores me marca en el log:

```
#0 /home/paginawe/public_html/educandoamorosamente.com/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/MetaDataReader.php(27): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerFile('/home/paginawe/...')
#1 /home/paginawe/public_html/educandoamorosamente.com/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Manager.php(42): MercadoPago\MetaDataReader->__construct()
#2 /home/paginawe/public_html/educandoamorosamente.com/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/SDK.php(34): MercadoPago\Manager->__construct(Object(MercadoPago\RestClient), Object(MercadoPago\Config))
#3 /home/paginawe/public_html/educandoamorosamente.com/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/SDK.php(43): MercadoPago\SDK::initialize in /home/paginawe/public_html/educandoamorosamente.com/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php on line 75
```

Comment: Usas dobre punto y coma en algunos casos, ej:  `$item = new MercadoPago\Item();;` y eso puede provocar un error 500 en el server, por favor revisalo y si el problema persiste indicalo

Comment: @Caldodeparticulasprimigenio gracias por la observación, lo acabo de corregir pero aun así me sigue marcando el error.

Comment: ¿El require está encontrando el recurso `autoload.php`? en caso de no encontrarlo require detiene el script, el fallo podría venir pro ahí

Comment: Los errores 500 son errores en el servidor. Revisa el log de errores en tu servidor remoto. Te dirá exactamente la causa del problema y en qué archivo y línea ocurre.

Comment: Gracias por contestarme ya cheque el log y me salen los siguientes errores

Comment: @Caldodeparticulasprimigenio ya cheque lo de autoload.php y no hay ningun error ahí, solo los errores del log pero no se a que se deba.

Comment: Este error es más del lado API de MercadoPago lo cual te recomiendo no mover. Compara los settings locales con el server remoto. Por ejemplo la versión del PHP puede ser algo clave.

Comment: entonces el asunto va con el SDK. Yo lo genere con este comando como me indicaba la pagina require "mercadopago/dx-php"

Comment: @AaronGC ya lo resolví era exactamente lo que decías, la versión de php de mi servidor

Comment: muchas gracias a todos por tomarse el tiempo de ayudarme.

Comment: para conocer el error que te está dando en producción, por favor añade este código <?php ini_st("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné actualizando la versión de php y haciendo la comparación de la versión local (que funcionaba) con la remota (el problema). Saludos!

Comment: Normalmente es importante que las versiones de PHP y sus extensiones, de local y remoto coincidan.

Comment: Sí, tenés razón. Me había olvidado de configurar el servicio de hosting recientemente contratado.